# What is the best way to hide a div container using css?

Tags: css

I've tried using

```
#div{
    display: hide;
}
```

but its not working.

Comment: Try `display : none`.

Comment: #div{ display : none }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple 'display:none' is the easiest way.
If you are showing and hiding dynamically, you can set a hidden class and use it like with jquery:

#### HTML

```html
<div id="mydiv" class="hidden"></div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.hidden
{
    display: none;
}
```

#### jQuery

```js
 $(function () {
     $('#mydiv').removeClass('hidden');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try  `display:none`

```
#div{
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
div {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

This will more or less make the element invisible, but it will still take up space.

Or use:

```
div {
display: none;
}
```

This will remove the element and the space it takes off the page completely.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the selector while applying css property to it.

> If your 'div' is a tag name like

```
<div>Your content </div>
```

You need to use

```
div {  // just the tag name
  display : none;
}
```

> else,

if it is the id of html element like

```
<p id="div">Your content</p>

//or

<div id="div"><Your content</div>
```

You should use

```
#div { //'id' with '#' before
  display : none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@CMadi is right but a good way of doing this is to create the following css class:

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

Now you can re-use class on as many divs as you want to hide by applying it to said div.

```
<div id="myDivId" class="hidden"></div>
```

This is also great if you want to dynamically make it invisible using javaScript in the following way.

```
var element = document.getElementById("myDivId");
element.classList.add("hidden");
```

Were you using jQuery you could hide an element with the following line of code.

```
$("#myDivId").addClass("hide");
```

And make it visible again with the following:

```
$("#myDivId").removeClass("hide");
```