# Best way to Hide A specific class, it has a specific name

Tags: html, css

Seems that hiding a element can be done 500 ways.  I'm looking what what is best for browser compatibility standards, and possibly even performance...

This is what I wish to hide:

```
<li class="header-menu-user"><a class="header-user" href="/Settings/User/UserProfile">User Settings</a></li>
```

What I have tried in the past is for another scenario in which I did a display:none on a  li with a data- attribute etc..

I just tried to do this and it is not working (not hiding it)

```
.header-user {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem about using CSS?

Comment: Are you wanting to hide it dynamically based on an action which would require javascript?  Or just on page load which only would require basic CSS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to hide a div container using css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271249/what-is-the-best-way-to-hide-a-div-container-using-css)

Comment: Not dynamic,  just always  ( Its a 3rd party bolted on product that gets modified with upgrades a lot - so removing the code from html etc.. is not desirable.

Comment: Target the surrounding `li` element... `.header-menu-user { display: none; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide a specific `<a>` tag like this:

```
li.header-menu-user a[href^="/Settings"] { display: none; }
```

Comment: Works great!   Thanks !

Comment: is it hiding the a tag but the li tag is still showing?

Comment: inspect the code in the firefox inspector and you will be able to figure out what exactly is going on

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways but one of these two usually is appropriate:

```
display: none;
```

Will hide the element, meaning surrounding elements will ignore it as if it were not in the DOM, even though it is and you can still target it.

```
opacity: 0;
```

Will essentially make the element transparent, not visible but it still occupies space in various layout models.

Comment: don't forget about `visibility: hidden;` which is probably the same as the opacity option

Comment: But how exactly should I hide it with traversing through <li> tag and the class ?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  Please hash it out more completely in your original question with the "edit" link.

Comment: @ChadJacobs .whatever-selector { display: none; } Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

With just using CSS `Display:none;` would be the way to go. The only performance impact this is really having is that you are still sending all the content that is hidden to the client browser. If you want to improve performance perhaps consider removing the content on the server side if that is an option for you.

Comment: But how exactly should I hide it with traversing through  <li> tag and the class ?

Comment: simply stick a class on the one you want to hide.  `li.hide { display:none; }`

Comment: You are only hiding the link, you want to hide the whole `<li>` tag.  `.header-menu-user { display: none; }`

Comment: How do I include the li tag and the class

Comment: huh?  I gave you the code and Simran gave you the code to hide `<li>` tag by targeting the class on the tag.

Comment: `li.header-menu-user { display: none; }`

Comment: @dmikester1   - thx,  another issue is that too many li tags with same class, so now I also need to have it look for the keyword  `user`  , thoughts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189975/discussion-between-dmikester1-and-chad-jacobs).